# Dynamic columns report by using MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table data something like following:

```
 CompanyName     Amount        Date
 -------------------------------------
 CompanyA        150.00     2013-01-02
 CompanyB         40.00     2013-01-05
 CompanyC         75.00     2013-02-02
 CompanyA        250.00     2013-02-12
 CompanyB        100.00     2013-03-27
 CompanyC        350.00     2013-04-01
    .
    .
    .
```

I need to build a report with date range and selected company as following:

```
 Company    Jan-13  Feb-13  Mar-13  Apr-13  May-13  ...   Total
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 Company A  $150    $239    $30     $500    $0      ...   $1,809
 Company B  $80     $0      $150    $200    $0      ...   $1,730
 Company C  $50     $30     $239    $0      $150    ...   $2,033
 Company D  $600    $150    $80     $30     $25     ...   $1,100
 Company E  $0      $50     $30     $150    $100    ...   $1,080
    .
    .
    .
    .
 MonthlyAmt $2,952   $1,377 $1,828  $2,470  $1,405  ...   $25,608
```

Please note that the Month columns are dynamic depend on the date range input.

So is SQL or Linq can retrieve data sweetly like that?

If cannot, my rough idea is get the one row data first like following:

```
 Company A  Amount
 -----------------
 Jan-13     150
 Feb-13     239
 Mar-13     30
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

After that use a loop to collect all the data and put it in an array ViewBag.
Then assign the data in View Page.
But if like that, there will be no sorting function and pagelist function.
May I know is there any better idea for this? Or this is the limitation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete example checked in linqpad (filtering by date is left out of scope)
and it does not produce records for all months for all companies if there are not transactions for that month.

```
void Main()
{
    var transactions = new List<transaction>(){
        new transaction() {
            volume = 5,
            company = "company1",
            date = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.15")
        },
        new transaction() {
            volume = 15,
            company = "company1",
            date = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.25")
        },
        new transaction() {
            volume = 25,
            company = "company2",
            date = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.25")
        },
        new transaction() {
            volume = 35,
            company = "company2",
            date = DateTime.Parse("2012.11.25")
        },
        new transaction() {
            volume = 45,
            company = "company3",
            date = DateTime.Parse("2012.12.25")
        },
    };

    transactions.Dump();

    var allTransactionsViewModel = transactions
            .GroupBy(t=>new {t.company,t.date.Month})
            .GroupBy(g=>g.Key.company, g=>new{g.Key.Month ,Total= g.Sum(t=>t.volume)})
            ;

    allTransactionsViewModel.Dump();        
}


class transaction {
 public int volume;
 public string company;
 public DateTime date;
}
```

so then you can

```
    table   
      @foreach(var g in allTransactionsViewModel){  
       tr
        @foreach(var s in g){  
          td @s.total /td  
        }  
       /tr  
    /table
```

Comment: It seems that allTransactionsViewModel will become null.